# How do I solve for T?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve for $T$ in the following equation: $$V_f = V_i + AT +  \frac 1 2JT^2.$$ Does anyone know how? I tried myself but since I'm 33 I can no longer remember basic algebra :(.

Thanks

Comment: If as in the edit the last term is $\frac{1}{2}JT^2$, you use the Quadratic Formula. If the last term is supposed to be $\frac{1}{2JT^2}$, then in principle one could use the Cardano Formula for cubics, but in practice a numerical method is best.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It looks like a physics equation $V_i$, $V_f$ are initial and final velocity, $J$ (jerk?)and $A$ (acceleration?) should be other magnitudes, so $\frac 1 2JT^2$ makes sense.

Comment: You are undoubtedly right. My monitor is too fuzzy for me to read subscripts.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, it looks like you're right about [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)).

Comment: yes I am trying to figure out the stopping distance of a ship in water knowing only velocity and time. The deceleration rate is not constant, which would require jerk. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** You have a quadratic equation in $T$. Recall that we can solve $$aT^2+bT+c=0$$ using the formula $$T=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

You have $$ (V_i-V_f) + AT +  \frac 1 2JT^2=0$$

so $$\begin{align}V_i-V_f=&c\;\\A=&b\\\frac 1 2J=&a\end{align}$$

Comment: (-A + Sqrt(A^2 - 4(1/2J)(Vi-Vf))) / 2(1/2J) ??

Comment: If you mean $$\frac{{ - A \pm \sqrt {{A^2} - 2J\left( {{V_i} - {V_f}} \right)} }}{J}$$ then yes.

Comment: Thank You Peter. I know it takes time to write that stuff out, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does it make a difference if it is a + or a - after the -A, will it always come out to the same answer regardless? Thanks

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle Well, no. If you didn't know, a quadratic equation **can** have two different solutions (which are given by the $\pm$). For example $x^2-3x+2=0$ has $x=1$ and $x=2$ as solutions.

Comment: Hmmmm... I guess one of those solutions for T would have to be negative then, because it's impossible for T two have two separate positive values considering it is time, I would think.

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle Sure, you should pick the positive solution here!

Comment: @scuzzlebuzzle The negative solution is meaningful too. It tells you how long ago the ship was last stationary!

Answer (score 2):

In general, given a quadratic equation
$$x^2+px+q=0,$$
we can "complete the square" to turn this into something we can solve more easily.

Specifically, we first rewrite the equation as
$$x^2+2\left(\frac12 p\right)x+q=0.$$

Note, then that because $(x+w)^2=x^2+2w+w^2$, we can write
$$\left(x+\frac 1 2 p\right)^2-\left(\frac 1 2 p\right)^2+q=0.$$
Then $$x+\frac12 p=\pm\sqrt {\frac{p^2}4-q},$$
so $$x=\frac{-p\pm\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}.$$
Now in general, $x^2$ may have a coefficient other than $1$. If we have an equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=0,$$
we divide through by $a$ to get
$$x^2+\frac b a x + \frac c a = 0,$$
so $$\begin{array}{cc}p=\frac b a & q=\frac c a\end{array}$$
and substituting gets us $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$